# Converting File object to Image object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, compression

So I have a website (using AngularJS) that lets users upload files via tag

```
<input type="file" ng-model="image" id="trigger" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)" accept="image/*">
```

When I handle the upload in the controller the image gets stored as a File object. This is my method that saves the file and also sets variables to preview the image

```
$scope.setFile = function (element) {
    $scope.image = element.files[0]; // This is my image as a File
    var reader = new FileReader();

    //This is for previewing the image
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        $scope.image_source = event.target.result;
        $scope.$apply();

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
}
```

Now I am trying to compress the image using J-I-C library found here: https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C/blob/master/src/JIC.js

But this library accepts an image object as its parameter and returns it as a compressed image object.  I can't seem to find a way to convert my $scope.image File object into an Image object. How would I go about doing this?

I would also need to convert the compressed image object back into a File so I can upload it to my Azure storage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to create an [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) instance, and set it's `src` to your [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). Then pass it to JIC:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = $scope.image_source;
jic.compress(img,...)
```

It then just uses a `canvas` element to manipulate the image, generate a new data url, and creates a new `Image` instance, setting its `src` to the data url. So when you get the compressed image back just take the `src` and use [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) to decode the base64 encoded data back into binary and create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). You can use `Blob` in most places that you would use `File`, for instance like uploading through ajax.

```
var newImg = jic.compress(oldImg,...);
//replace 'image/png' with the proper image mime type
var base64data = newImg.src.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
var bs = atob(base64data);
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bs.length);
var ba = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < bs.length; i++) {
    ba[i] = bs.charCodeAt(i);
}
var blob = new Blob([ba],{type:"image/png"});
//now use blob like you would any other File object
```

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what I needed.

Comment: Having a similar issue:

jic.js:22 Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

 var preview = document.querySelector('#preview_image'+x);
    var file    = document.querySelector('#images'+x).files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = file.src;


    img.src = jic.compress(img,70,'jpg').src;

Any Ideas?